# Where did I go wrong in solving this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The value of the expression $ax^2 + bx + 1$ are $1$ and $4$ when $x$ takes the values of $2$ and $3$ respectively. Find the value of the expression when $x$ takes the value of $4.$

Here is my first attempt at solving this question:

\begin{align}
2a^2 + 2b + 1 &= 1 \leftarrow\text{(1)} \\
3a^2 + 3b + 1 &= 4 \leftarrow\text{(2)}
\end{align}

$$ \text{From (1):} $$

\begin{align}
2a^2 + 2b + 1 &= 1 \\
2a^2 &= -2b + 1 - 1 \\
2a^2 &= -2b \\
a^2 &= -b \leftarrow\text{(3)}
\end{align}

$$ \text{Substitute (3) into (2):} $$

\begin{align}
3(-b) + 3b + 1 &= 4 \\
-3b + 3b + 1 &= 4 \\
1 &= 4
\end{align}

Here is my second attempt at solving it:

\begin{align}
ax^2 + bx + 1 &= 1 \\
2a^2 + 2b + 1 &= 1 \\
a^2 + b + \frac{1}{2} &= \frac{1}{2} \\
a^2 + b &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\
a^2 + b &= 0 \\
4a^2 + 4b &= 0 \\
4a^2 + 4b + 1 &= 1 \leftarrow\text{(1)}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
3a^2 + 3b + 1 &= 4 \\
3a^2 + 3b &= 4 - 1 \\
3a^2 + 3b &= 3 \\
a^2 + b &= 1 \\
4a^2 + 4b &= 4 \\
4a^2 + 4b + 1 &= 5 \leftarrow\text{(2)}
\end{align}

$$ \text{(1) = (2): } 1 = 5 $$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have to replace $x$ by the given values in the equation, not $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe sorry but I don't understand. What have I done instead?

Comment: Can you explain how you derive the very first line, $2a^2+2b+1=1$ ?

Comment: $ ax2+bx+1$ with $x=2$ gives $a2^2+b2+1=4a+2b+1$. Get sober and try again ;-)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe the question said _The value of the expression $ax^2+bx+1$ are $1$ and $4$ when $x$ takes the values of $2$ and $3$ respectively_, so I substituted $x$ with $2$ and, the value is $1$, hence obtaining $2a^2+2b+1=1$

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur Did you *really* substitute $x$ with $2$ ?... Read carefully what you wrote...

Comment: "Where I have I gone wrong?" - You confused (a,b) with (x,y). The equations you have are $a\cdot  2^2+b\cdot 2+1=1$ and $a\cdot 3^2+b\cdot 3+1=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in $(1)$

Since the equation is

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+1$$

And the value when $x=2$ is $1$, equation one should be

$$f(2)=a2^2+b2+1\\
1=4a+2b+1\\
2a=-b\\
a=\frac{-b}{2}$$

Substituting in (2)

$$f(3)=9a+3b+1\\
4=9\left(\frac{-b}{2}\right)+3b+1\\
6=-9b+6b\\
b=-2\\
\therefore a=1$$

So when $x=4$

$$f(4)=4^2-2\cdot4+1=9$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

- $p(2)=1 \implies 4a + 2b + 1=1$
- $p(3)=4 \implies 9a + 3b + 1=4$

then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 4a + 2b + 1 = 1 \leftarrow\text{(1)} $$
$$ 9a + 3b + 1 = 4 \leftarrow\text{(2)} $$

$$ 4a + 2b = 0 $$
$$ 9a + 3b = 3 $$

$$a=1, b=-2$$